# Можно ли подключить *.tlb(typeLibrary) к Java приложению?

Tags: java, ole

Можно ли подключить *.tlb к Java, чтобы подключить к приложению программу как Excel, Word, Femap.

Знаю, что в Visual Basic и C++ это не проблема, а вот то насчёт Java?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое - http://j-interop.org/

Comment: @ICE, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.